# Discuss the convergence of sequence $ (a_n )$ and series $\sum a_n$ where $a_n = \frac{1+2^{-2}+...+n^{-2}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am working on the following problem.

Let $a_n = \frac{1+2^{-2}+...+n^{-2}}{n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.Then I have to check the convergence of both the sequence $(a_n)$ and the series $\sum a_n$.

**My attempt:**  Let $\alpha_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ then using this result if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\alpha_n=L$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n}n=L$, I observe that the sequence $(a_n)$ convergese as the limit of sequence $a_n = \frac{1+2^{-2}+...+n^{-2}}{n}$ is zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Am I on the right path? How to check the convergence of the series $\sum a_n$. I am stucked here.

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Comparison series / integral will help here!

Comment: Have you heard about [Cesaro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) ?

Comment: For the series you can use $a_n\ge 1/n$ and recall the harmonic series.

Comment: @Matija Could you write this as an answer. I will be able to do after that by using comparison test. Thank you so much

Comment: @JeanMarie It would add up to my knowledge if I could use this to solve current problem.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Could you write answer or little hint so that I can proceed. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to prove that the sequence

$a_n=\dfrac{1+2^{-2}+3^{-2}+\ldots+n^{-2}}n$

converges to $\,0\,$ as $\,n\to\infty\,.$

Since $\;k^{-2}=\dfrac1{k^2}<\dfrac1{k(k\!-\!1)}=\dfrac1{k\!-\!1}-\dfrac1k\;,\;$ for any $\,k\geqslant2\;,\;$

it results that
$0<a_n=\dfrac{1\!+\!\sum\limits_{k=2}^nk^{-2}}n<\dfrac{1\!+\!\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\!\left(\frac1{k-1}\!-\!\frac1k\right)}n=\dfrac{1\!+\!1\!-\!\frac1n}n<\dfrac2n$

for any $\;n\geqslant2\,.$

Actually, also for $\,n=1\,$ it results that $\,\;0<a_n<\dfrac2n\;.$

Hence, $\;0<a_n<\dfrac2n\;,\;$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;$ and , by applying the Squeeze Theorem, we get that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\,.$

Comment: Thank you so much for this simplest explanation.

Comment: @Srijan, you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-2}=1+\sum_{k=2}^nk^{-2}=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\int\unicode{120793}\{k-1<x<k\}k^{-2}\mathrm dx\le1+\int_1^nx^{-2}\mathrm dx=1+1-n^{-1},$$
so we have $a_n\le 2/n$ and hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$. On the other hand, we have $a_n\ge 1/n$ and hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty,$$
since the latter sum is the harmonic series. To be more precise, using another integral bound, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\int\unicode{120793}\{k<x<k+1\}\frac1k\mathrm dx\ge\int_1^{n+1}\frac1x\mathrm dx=\ln(n+1).$$
In particular, this shows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.